# Override Web Application permissions from site level permission

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepointadmin

I am stuck with a permission issue.

Any user can register with my site. A registered user can view only all the pages (site pages library) in the site. They shouldn't see view all content or open any other list.

So i have denied the "View Application Pages" from centraladmin->webapp->permission policy

Everything is going well.

Now i have another requirement,

I want to give "Create page permission" from site level for some set of users. So what i did is, i created a sharepoint group called "Creators" and gave Add List Item permission and view list item permission.

Now the "Creators" user not able to view the list items and 'view all site content' option. Because i have denied that in permission policy.

How can i override the webapplication level policy from my site. Or any other alternate solution for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the all site contents link for the groups to whom you dont want to show the View All site contents link.

Try this..

http://www.apps4rent.com/support/kb/article/remove-view-all-site-content-sharepoint

Correct me if I misunderstood your requirement